# how to perfom a getItem and updateItem in a transaction with dynamodb with go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

This is the fist time using dynamo and y dont know how to retrieve and record and also update the status of that record in a transaction.
I have a table "product" and I need to select one record with `attribute1 = abc and isUsed = false` and then update its status to `isUsed = true`.

Product

| pk (hash) | attribute1 | isUsed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc | true |
| 345 | abc | false |
| 456 | abc | false |
| 567 | qwe | false |

All de documentation talk about the use of `transactionWriteItem` and `transactionGetItem` but I don't know how to do the get and update in the same transacction. Is there a way to do this?

I need to do something like this:

1. find a record and use the pk of that record to update it.

```
twii := &dynamodb.TransactWriteItemsInput{
        TransactItems: []*dynamodb.TransactWriteItem{
            {
                Get: &dynamodb.Get{
                    Item:                av2,
                    TableName:           aws.String(product),
                    ConditionExpression: aws.String("..."),
                },
            },
            {
                Update: &dynamodb.Update{
                    Item:                av,
                    TableName:           aws.String(activationTable),
                    ConditionExpression: aws.String("..."),
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html

Comment: What is your current code and why it does not work?

Comment: if I use the TransactionWriteItem this only allows use Delete, Put and Update, so I can't put the Get to obtain the record.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions can only read or write, not both.

You don't list your actual needs, but if I'm guessing right: you need to do a get (or query), manipulate the item client-side, then put the new version.

To ensure you're not overwriting some other thread's changes in between your read and write, you may want to use "optimistic locking" and have a version number or last modified timestamp on each item and issue a condition expression as part of the write to make sure it's still the same as when you got it. It's a common idiom.

Note that in DynamoDB a condition expression is a write feature, not a read feature. I noticed you used it in your pseudocode around the get. It's about enforcing the write happens only if a condition is satisfied (like that the timestamp hasn't changed).